# PyTest-BDD : Support for data tables without Scenario Outline

Tags: pytest, bdd

I have the following image as a test case

[image: user settings](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N9w5qaqC8AYUo5Sa2lvmsvqHLCgiPE8a)[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBwVE.png)

When using behave, we were writing a scenario like this

```
Given When user is logged in to the platform
When user opens the settings window
Then user should see the following values
    | Field                 | Value              |
    | Currency              | Reported currency  |
    | Conversion Method     | MI recommended     |
    | Magnitude             | Millions (6)       |
    | Display Null Value As | SOA_Null           |
    | Function Options      | Excluded from export |
    | Dynamic Field Labels  | Excluded from export |
```

We are now migrating to Pytest-BDD instead of Behave. But I couldn't find support for the above case in Pytest. I went through the Pytest-BDD documentation and the support they have is for Scenario Outline.

https://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

But my case is not a Scenario Outline since I have to run this scenario only once and not iterate over the Field-Value pairs mentioned above

I also looked into github and the closest I could find was this, but this doesn't seem to be approved yet.

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-bdd/pull/180

Does Pytest support implementation of the above scenario in any way? Is there a workaround, if not a direct way, to handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps...

Then response should have below attributes:

```
    |  attr                     |
    |  id                       |
    |  activityId               |
    |  activityName             |
    |  activityType             |
    |  processDefinitionId      |
    |  processDefinitionUrl     |
    |  processInstanceId        |
    |  processInstanceUrl       |
    |  executionId              |
    |  taskId                   |
    |  calledProcessInstanceId  |
    |  assignee                 |
    |  startTime                |
    |  endTime                  |
    |  durationInMillis         |
    |  tenantId                 |


Then verify response attribute values:
    |attr             |   attr_value        | path                  |
    |activityId       |   endProcessSubmit  | data[0].activityId    |
    |activityType     |   endEvent          | data[0].activityType  |


@then(parsers.parse ('response should have below attributes:\n{attr_table}'))

def verify_response_attributes(datatable,attr_table,query_historic_activity_instances):
    query_data = query_historic_activity_instances.json()['data']
    BaseTest.verify_tbl_attr(attr_table,query_data)

@then(parsers.parse('verify response attribute values:\n{attr_value_table}'))

def verify_response_attribute_values(datatable,attr_value_table,query_historic_activity_instances):
    query_data = query_historic_activity_instances.json()
    BaseTest.verify_tbl_attr_values(attr_value_table, query_data)


  @staticmethod
    def verify_tbl_attr_values(table_with_header,query_data):
        # datatable = parse_str_table(attr_value_table)
        list_attr=BaseTest.get_tbl_attr_values(table_with_header)
        # for row in range(len(datatable.rows)):
        #     attr = list(datatable.rows[row].values())[0]
        #     attr_val = list(datatable.rows[row].values())[1]
        #     path = list(datatable.rows[row].values())[2]
        for i in range(len(list_attr)):
            attr = list_attr[i][0]
            attr_val = list_attr[i][1]
            path = list_attr[i][2]
            for match in parse(path).find(query_data):
                assert attr_val == match.value, "The expected %s and Actual %s for %s Dint match" % (
                attr_val, match.value, attr)

    @staticmethod
    def get_tbl_attr_values(table_with_header):
        datatable = parse_str_table(table_with_header)
        list_attr_val = []
        for row in range(len(datatable.rows)):
            list_attr_val.append(list(datatable.rows[row].values()))
        return list_attr_val

    @staticmethod
    def verify_tbl_attr(table_with_header,query_data):
        list_attr = BaseTest.get_tbl_attr(table_with_header)
        for i in range(len(query_data)):
            for j in range(len(list_attr)):
                assert list_attr[j] in query_data[i],"Response don't have %s" % list_attr[j]

    @staticmethod
    def get_tbl_attr(table_with_header):
        datatable = parse_str_table(table_with_header)
        list_attr = []
        for row in datatable.rows:
            for item in row:
                list_attr.append(row[item])
        return (list_attr)

    @staticmethod
    def verify_tbl_attr_by_column(table_with_header):
        datatable = parse_str_table(table_with_header)
        list_attr = []
        for column in datatable.columns.values():
                list_attr.append(column)
        return (list_attr)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer given above, the following method will be helpful to convert the string into a data-table in step definition:

```
def parse_str_table(self, table_with_headers):
    list_table_rows = table_with_headers.split("\n")
    list_headers = str(list_table_rows[0]).strip("|").split("|")
    dict_table = {}
    for header in list_headers:
        header_text = header.strip()
        lst_row = []
        for i in range(1, list_table_rows.__len__()):
            list_temp = list_table_rows[i].strip("|").split("|")
            lst_row.append(list_temp[list_headers.index(header)].strip())

        dict_table[header_text] = lst_row

    return dict_table
```